# How has the relative ratio of igneous, sedimentary, and metamorphic rocks changed over Earth's history?

Tags: geology

Has the relative ratio of sedimentary over igneous rocks increased, simply as a result of more and more of the Earth's rock being exposed to sedimentary processes?

Or has it increased only for the first billion years of Earth's history, and stayed fairly constant afterwards?